# Unique rows in data.frame

Tags: r

I have this data.frame:

```
  V1     V2
1 RAB27A RAD21
2 RAB27A STAT1
3 ITGA4  RAD21
4 PANK3  SIX5
5 PANK3  SREBF1
6 PANK3  USF1
```

And I would like it looks like this:

```
  V1     V2    V3     V4
1 RAB27A RAD21 STAT1
2 ITGA4  RAD21
3 PANK3  SIX5  SREBF1 USF1
```

I'm beginner. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(V2= toString(V2)), V1][, paste0("V", 2:4) :=tstrsplit(V2, ", ")][]
#       V1    V2     V3   V4
#1: RAB27A RAD21  STAT1   NA
#2:  ITGA4 RAD21     NA   NA
#3:  PANK3  SIX5 SREBF1 USF1
```

Or this can be done with just `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df1), V1~rowid(V1, prefix = "V"), value.var="V2")
#       V1    V1     V2   V3
#1:  ITGA4 RAD21     NA   NA
#2:  PANK3  SIX5 SREBF1 USF1
#3: RAB27A RAD21  STAT1   NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("RAB27A", "RAB27A", "ITGA4", "PANK3", "PANK3", 
"PANK3"), V2 = c("RAD21", "STAT1", "RAD21", "SIX5", "SREBF1", 
"USF1")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Here it is biased voting on play as I showed a compact option without any pasteing.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `aggregate`, `toString` (or`paste`/`paste0`) and the `cSplit` function from the `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
newdata <- cSplit(aggregate(V2 ~ V1, mydf, toString), 'V2', sep=',', direction='wide')
```

which gives:

```
> newdata
       V1  V2_1   V2_2 V2_3
1:  ITGA4 RAD21     NA   NA
2:  PANK3  SIX5 SREBF1 USF1
3: RAB27A RAD21  STAT1   NA
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newdf <- mydf %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(V2 = toString(V2)) %>% 
  separate(V2, paste0('V2_',1:3), sep = ',')
```

which gives:

```
> newdf
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

      V1  V2_1    V2_2  V2_3
  (fctr) (chr)   (chr) (chr)
1  ITGA4 RAD21      NA    NA
2  PANK3  SIX5  SREBF1  USF1
3 RAB27A RAD21   STAT1    NA
```

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text="V1     V2
                   1 RAB27A RAD21
                   2 RAB27A STAT1
                   3 ITGA4 RAD21
                   4 PANK3 SIX5
                   5 PANK3 SREBF1
                   6 PANK3 USF1", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: @akrun I know it was a dupe, but couldn't find a proper one at first. Your answer put me in the right direction ;-)